# Catch does not catch

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I create an ODBCConnection in X++, accessing an non-AX-SQL-object.
Everything works fine, if connection is established either via Windows-Auth or username/password-combination which access to db has been granted to.

The only lack is, that the `catch`-part does not get called, when

```
connection = new OdbcConnection( loginProperty );
```

is called and throws an error.

```
try
{
    connection = new OdbcConnection( loginProperty );
}
catch ( Exception::CLRError ) 
// also tried Exception::Error and catch without brackets
{
    info ('error occured...' );
}
```

I assume, perhaps Exception-type is not chosen wisely, right? But shouldn't `Exception::Error` or catch without params catch **all**?
[MSDN says, if a connection can not be established](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa554029%28v=ax.50%29.aspx), an exception is thrown. Shouldn't I be able to catch it?

What's the mistake / misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Proper CLR and Interop exceptions catching is described on the following link:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677495(v=ax.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677495%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps there's something I oversee, but I use `catch (Exception::CLRError)` ( even in OP ) and this code is **NOT** reached.

Comment: Sometimes the debugger don't stop inside catch statements (and some other places). Are you sure that exception is not catched? I've used this code many times without problems. Have you tried to put a general catch with an info() message? Just to be sure that this is not a problem with the debugger.

Comment: As written in OP, you can see an `info...` and the comment that I've also tried catch `( Exception::Error )` and a catch without brackets. `info` is not called but another ErrorMessage is thrown.